# Does a manifold of dimension one has curvature?

Tags: manifolds

Recently I have seen an interesting answer to an "obvious" question. That is "why can we pull a curve back into a line"? And the answer is "because a manifold of dimension one has no curvature". 
So I was wandering whether that answer is correct or not. Besides, I am not sure why a manifold of dim 1 has no curvature? Looking for someone's answer.

Comment: What do you mean by pulling a curve back into a line? If a curve intersects itself, then there can't be a continuous map from the curve to a line, let alone a homeomorphism or diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curves normally have extrinsic curvatures.

For example a circle with radius $R$ has extrinsic  curvature  of $1/R$.

May be the answer is that curves do not have intrinsic curvature which is another way of saying the intrinsic curvature of a curve is $0$.

Comment: The curvature of a circle is given by the way you consider it in a plane. But a circle (minus a point) is isometric to an interval.

Comment: That is correct. I think a circle without a point still has curvature even if it is isometric to an interval.

Comment: It has extrinsic curvature. But I think that the OP asks for intrinsic curvature. Maybe I am wrong.

Comment: I guess you are correct. It is quite possible for a curve to not have an intrinsic curvature.